# java convert timestamp in seconds to timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: java, performance

I want to convert timestamp in seconds to timestamp in milliseconds. Following is my naive approach.

```
if( timestamp < 10000000000 ) {
    timestamp = timestamp * 1000L;
}
```

Unfortunately I have to put this code in the server that receives thousands of requests every minute. So, I want to make this comparison as fast as possible.

I have a couple of questions:

1. How expensive is the naive approach?
2. Is there any faster way of handling this?

Comment: Have you determined this is actually a performance bottleneck relative to the rest of your app's functionality?

Comment: An `if` with a multiply and store? I would expect that to be inexpensive and very fast. Have you measured any performance problems?

Comment: All server does is get request and store the request data. We trust our clients that they will not send foul data. So, currently, there is absolutely no data processing going on. This is the first time we are processing data in the server.

Comment: For your `if` statement, is it possible for it to already be miliseconds? If not, you don't need the if statement, and if it can, what if your timestamp (in miliseconds) is legitimately below 100000000000? (don't count the zeros).

Comment: @DoubleDouble: it is possible that its already in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How expensive is the naive approach?

The condition will take about 1 ns and the `* 1000L` will take about 3 ns. So about 4 ns in total.
   If you do this 250 million times per second, you have a problem.  A few thousand a second I wouldn't worry about.

> Is there any faster way of handling this?

I am sure it is the lease of your problems in terms of performance.  I would use a CPU and measure where your problem are instead of guessing.

Comment: I disagree with your figures... the latency of a multiplication is 3 cycles on my old Core i5, which means about 1 ns (while still leaving room for ILP). The condition is nearly free if it can be predicted, otherwise it can cost a few cycles (17 cycles on Core i7 as written [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/amd-versus-intel-successes-and-pitfalls-of-their-processor-architectures-2-bulldozer-and-sandy-bridge-comparison)), i.e., about 5 ns. I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: Sure. I will put some stopwatches at appropriate places in my code and check how much does this affect time taken per request. I guess I should have done this before. I will comment after my experiments are done. Until then I will just close this question.

Comment: @riship89 The time stamps take about 35 ns at best (about 9x the code you have there) so measuring it is pretty hard.

Comment: then I have to wrap stopwatches with stopwatches. Inception!!! Just kidding. I was talking about logging time taken by API to respond with 200. If I log this for "n" concurrent requests with and without timestamp conversion opearation, I will get some numbers to look at.